# Open user control by button in another user control

Tags: wpf, user-controls

So, my set up is like this:

- My MainWindow has a `TabControl` with 5 tabs. To keep the code in my file clean I decided the 5 tabs their content into 5 `UserControls`.
- In let say tab 1 has `UserControl` Customers (View: CustomersView, ViewModel: CustomersViewModel) with a `ComboBox`. The ComboBox is `ItemSource` is bound to a `ObservableCollection(Of String)` which is filled by `DbServiceKlant.GetKlantenlijst`.
- Also in tab 1 I have a button to add a new Customer to the database. This opens another UserControl which overlays the entire MainWindow.
- This 2nd UserControl (View: AddCustomerView, ViewModel: AddCustomerViewModel) has some form to fill in, has a `Sub` to ass the data to the database.

I first did this all in the MainWindow but the code has taken on sushi proportions (both in .xaml and .xaml.vb) that it isn't maintainable anymore. Having everything in 1 file, it's easy to pass variables and add items to a ObservableCollection.

With everything split up in UserControls, it has been a question to me how I'm going to achieve this. Basically:

- UserControl `Customers` has a `ObservableCollection` filled with `Customer` and a button to open UserControl `AddCustomer`.
- In UserControl AddCustomer I have a button which can add the filled in form to the database.

Now the question is:

- How do I open UserControl AddCustomer from Customers?
- How do I update my ObservableCollection in Customers if I close AddCustomer?

When everything was in 1 file I just manipulated `Visibility` of AddCustomer and could update the ObservableCollection.

This is a snippet from `Customers`.

```
<ComboBox Background="White" ItemsSource="{Binding Klantenlijst}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedKlant}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" />
<Button Grid.Column="5" Command="{Binding OpenAddKlant}" ToolTip="Nieuwe klant">
    <Image Source="/Images/Add.png" />
</Button>
```

The ObservableCollection.

```
Private _oKlantenlijst As ObservableCollection(Of String) = DbServiceKlant.GetKlantenlijst
Public Property Klantenlijst As ObservableCollection(Of String)
    Get
        Return _oKlantenlijst
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of String))
        _oKlantenlijst = value
        OnPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property
```

The ICommand:

```
Private _oOpenAddKlant As New RelayCommand(AddressOf OpenAddKlantSub)
Public ReadOnly Property OpenAddKlant As RelayCommand
    Get
        Return _oOpenAddKlant
    End Get
End Property
```

And the actual `Sub`

```
Public Sub OpenAddKlantSub()
    ' I think here should be the code to open the AddCustomer UserControl
End Sub
```

In my 1 file application (which I'm converting to UserControls), the AddCustomer popup had this `Sub`

```
Private Sub PopUpAddKlantAdd(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Try
        If PupAddKlaNaa.Equals("") OrElse PupAddKlaStr.Equals("") OrElse PupAddKlaGem.Equals("") Then
            MessageBox.Show("U moet minstens de naam, straat en gemeente invullen om een nieuwe klant aan te kunnen maken.", "Geen gegevens", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information)
        Else
            DbServiceKlant.Create(PupAddKlaNaa, PupAddKlaStr, PupAddKlaNr_, PupAddKlaBus, PupAddKlaPos, PupAddKlaGem, PupAddKlaLan, PupAddKlaTel, PupAddKlaBTW)
            _oKlant = DbServiceKlant.GetDetails(PupAddKlaNaa) 
            PopUpAddKlantClose()
            PopUpAddKlantClear()
            VoGetNaamKlanten()
            VoFillDetailsKlant(_oKlant)
            VoKlaSel = _oKlant.Naam
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ExceptionLogger.Log(ex, 1)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you want to show this user control when clicked?

Comment: It has to overlay the MainWindow. In the MainWindow is the TabControl with tab 1 the Customers UserControl. This UserControl has the button. This is a screenshot from my 1 in all file application: http://i1054.photobucket.com/albums/s485/KFredje/PrtScr_zps92510f8c.jpg

PS: Don't mind the Dutch ;)